# Detect an indecomposable distribution through its Laplace transform?

Tags: decomposition

I would like to decide whether a random variable $X$ is an [indecomposable distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_distribution). In this situation $X$ is obtained from real-life measurements - say $(x_n)_n$ - so it's not a particular closed form expression.

Does anyone has an idea how to assess the decomposability of $X$? (ideally through an algorithm)

Ps: I am currently considering using the Laplace transform of the distribution as it feels it could help offering a better viewpoint, but the detail is still unclear to me.

Comment: Can you clarify this question, you have some data $X$ and you are going to take a Laplace transform of some distribution $f$.  I assume $f$ is from an "empirical distribution," can you clarify what you mean by that?  
If we use an ECDF, and the ECDF isn't a point mass, then we can just split by the median and say anything below the median and half the mass at the median belongs to one random variable and anything above is the probability mass of another random variable.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to improve the phrasing of the question. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Because it's empirical, it's discrete, and therefore can only decompose into other discrete distributions.  That imposes such strong patterns that it looks like obtaining a decomposable distribution will be exceptionally rare.  It certainly won't tell you whether the underlying distribution is decomposable.  Could you therefore explain why you are trying to accomplish this?

Comment: I am facing measurements obtained from physical system that has several modes. In some of the modes, the physical system is really the sum of a large number of independent subsystems - as far you can ever get truly independent systems in real-life. The measurements are capturing the ensemble. However, in some other modes, the system is much more monolithic, possibly with a single subsystem. Subsystems are not observed, only the measurement of the sum. Yet, I would like to be assess some properties of the subsystems. Decomposability seemed to make sense.